# On the way finding limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, trigonometry, exponential-function

> **Find The Limit** $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$$

**My Approach**

We know that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}
= 1$$

So $$\lim_{x\to0}
\left[ 1+\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}-1\right)\right]
^{\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}-1\right)}\right)\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)}
=e^{\left[\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\right]}$$

From here I tried many methods but couldn’t get the solution. I also tried
the logrithmic approach but everything got messesed up.

Comment: Use Taylor series $\tan x=x+\dfrac{x^{3}}{3}+o(x^{3})$

Comment: I made a few edits so that your question is more easy to read. I tried to not change the symbols or appearance. I have some suggestions: **(1)** Define $u=\tan(x)/x$ to save space. **(2)** Use $\frac{1}{f(x)}=[f(x)]^{-1}$ to decrease the number of lines. **(3)** Use the notation $e^x=\exp x$.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor i use use lyx .Can you tell me how to highlight the question as you did in the edit

Comment: For example, this would make the last expression into $$\lim_{x\to0}[1+(u-1)]^{(u-1)^{-1}(u-1)^{1}x^{-2}}=\exp\left[\lim_{x\to0}(u-1)x^{-2}\right]$$

Comment: @KislayTripathi Precede the text with `>`. You can click “Edit” to see what I typed.

Comment: @KislayTripathi Yes, but let’s do it in chat. You can also look at the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and explore the `faq` (“frequently asked questions”) tag on Meta. (I am in the United States, and it is 1:13 AM here, so I am going to sleep. I can respond in the morning, of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\tan{x}}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(1+\frac{\tan{x}}{x}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{\tan{x}}{x}-1}\frac{\frac{\tan{x}}{x}-1}{x^2}}=$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\sin{x}-x\cos{x}}{x^3}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos{x}}\right)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos{x}-\cos{x}+x\sin{x}}{3x^2}}=e^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Form the known form $\lim_{x\to 0} f (x)^{g (x)}=1^{\infty} $ the limit is given by $e^ {\lim_{x\to 0} (f (x)-1).g (x)} $ so in your case it will be $e^{\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\tan(x)-x}{x^3}} $ now as given in comments use Taylor series of $\tan (x) $ to get the answer as $e^{\frac {1}{3 }} $

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}=e^{\lim_{x\to0}\ln\left(\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}\right)}=e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)}{x^2}}=e^{\frac{0}{0}}\\\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}-\dfrac{\tan\left(x\right)-x\sec^2\left(x\right)}{2x^2\tan\left(x\right)}=-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2x\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)}{4x\tan\left(x\right)+2x^2\sec^2\left(x\right)}=\\-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-4x\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan^2\left(x\right)-2\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)-2x\sec^4\left(x\right)}{4x^2\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)+4\tan\left(x\right)+8x\sec^2\left(x\right)}=\\-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-8x\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan^3\left(x\right)-8\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan^2\left(x\right)-16x\sec^4\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)-4\sec^4\left(x\right)}{8x^2\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan^2\left(x\right)+24x\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)+4x^2\sec^4\left(x\right)+12\sec^2\left(x\right)}\\=-\frac{-4}{12}=\frac{1}{3}\\\therefore\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}=e^{\frac{1}{3}}$$